# Binding Listbox in Silverlight with DataContext defined from Resource

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, ria

How to bind a Listbox in silverlight with DataContext option.I want to have a resource defined in the Usercontrol and want to use it as a static resource List box control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you well, do you want to have a list box binded to a static resource list of items?,  then this would be one way to do it:

I have done it with itemssource not with datacontext, if that's a good approach for you this is what you need to do:

Define the class  for each one of the items and another class that will be a list of items

```
namespace Dashboard.Models
    {
        public class StringValue
            {
                #region Properties

                public string Value { get; set; }

                #endregion
            }
        public class ValueList : List<StringValue>
            { }
    }
```

In your xaml code in the usercontrol declaration add the reference to the namespace

```
xmlns:LocalModels="clr-namespace:Dashboard.Models"
```

Add the static resource to your usercontrol

```
<Grid.Resources>
<LocalModels:ValueList x:Key="States">
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="--"></LocalModels:StringValue>
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="AL"></LocalModels:StringValue>
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="AK"></LocalModels:StringValue>
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="AZ"></LocalModels:StringValue>
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="AR"></LocalModels:StringValue>
                <LocalModels:StringValue Value="CA"></LocalModels:StringValue>
 </LocalModels:ValueList>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Reference your listbox to the static resource

```
ItemsSource="{StaticResource States}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Value"
```

Hope it helps.